# How to prevent jumps on movement of object by onMouseMove?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

*<sub>This has might been answered but can't find any positive results on search.</sub>*

Having a script to move elements around using various extra calculations beyond the 
*"normal"* x,y positioning.

I'm not using JQuery or any other libraries, but here is a sample on the core:
**>> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YQLJa/) <<**

The issue at hand is that when moving the element it sometimes does not update, as in:
when pointer is moved the element stand still, then a big jump come along.

This, for some reason happens most often when moving slowly. *(Perhaps it does it all the
time but on fast movements it isn't as noticeable.)*

I see this *effect* when doing plain move to x,y as well, but not quite as often.

***Question is what causes this and hopefully how to fix.***

I have tried to add a check on time as in if last *mousemove*-event was e.g. 10 ms ago do nothing. Not any better.

Have also tried to put the positioning of the element in a timeout as in:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    element.style.left = x + 'px';
    element.style.top  = y + 'px';
}, 0);
```

to let the browser do other work, but not any better.

*This is most noticeable in Mozilla Firefox of the browsers I have tested. Opera
is definitively the smoothest.*

---

***EDIT:***

Added a simple

```
 console.log('1');
```

And I notice that when the movement hangs the log also hangs (does not log).

It is as in `446 events`, lag, `447 events`.

So it has to stand somewhere in the region of event not triggered or similar.

---

***EDIT:***

@kenansulayman:

To clarify. I do not use the `setTimeout()` – I *tested* with it, also using 0,1,2,3,5,10,15,...,500+, with no better results:

I also have tested by using this:

On mouse down start this:

```
Drag.int = 0;
Drag.eint = setInterval(function(){Drag.int++}, 1); /* 1 being variable. */
```

And on `move` add `console.log(Drag.eint)` – when lag/stop of movement happens – `Drag.int` increases by 1. There is never a gap. As in:

```
447
448
449 <-- lag, movement stop, aprox 1-1.5 seconds
450
451
```

Not if I include the `setTimeout()` either with say
timeout of 10 or 20.

If I'm totally missing the point – please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to work-around client-side lag situations. However, I propose a simple interpolation of the ]x|y[ coordinates.

That is, you can do the following:

1. initiate an interval capturing cached ]x|y[ coordinates (by 2.)
2. initiate an interval capturing the ]x|y[ coordinates.

Now test the recent *k* captured coordinates for outliers (which applies to a case where a jump (lag) occurs) and interpolate the jump.

Advanced proposal:

[image: Interpolation, higher degree]

Whereas *n* be the degree of the interpolation. Typically for your application a value between ]4|7[ is appropriate.

As for the outlier detection, I suggest using the basic ***Grubbs' test for outliers*** or the ***Stahel-Donoho Outlyingness***.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tried this before I in my dumbness realized it was nothing to process – as in no way to capture without event – and no event executed. (Should have tested that beforehand). Issue is that there is no way to poll second point. That is; what I did was add a routine that calculated the direction of the movement and speed and set the position accordingly. But this made for buggy movement as if lag happens on stop of move. – Issue is then as described by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2601273/1968548). If I missed something, please let me know. +1.

Comment: Let me get this straight. It is possible. In fact, intervals are the only low-level way to implement controllers to be adapted. For instance, a PS3s' data stream does not provide events (as everything low level), you need to poll. Events are even more laggy than polling. However, try increasing the setInterval(.., 0) to 10 or 5. Null means NextTick, thus pollutes the CPU and doesn't do anything constructive but reading the same values a few million times per second. :) ***Edit:*** As of that, your 0-interval maybe the source of your lagging. "Nooooo" is not an answer, though.

Comment: There's no lag in the Fiddle-example here. What browser are you using and what are your specs? Safari 6.0.3 / OSX 10.8.4 here.

Comment: This is currently on a Ubuntu box using Gnome classic and various "most extra candy removed". Most noticeable on Firefox (19.0.2). Actually I'm having trouble reproducing it under Opera, Chrome, Safari etc. Firefox test profile is clean with no plugins etc. I once loved FF. Today I hate it.

Comment: Firefox Nightly 23a1: OK. Chrome 28.0.1474.0: OK. Safari 6.0.3: OK. IE 10: OK. Opera 12.5: OK. Don't see your issues :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28114/discussion-between-kenansulayman-and-zimzalabim)